# R Shiny HTML hyperlink to seperate page containing chart

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, shiny

I have been trying for the last 2.5 hours to figure this out. I have managed to create a custom navigation bar with three links for my ShinyApp. My ShinyApp consists of 3 charts: a bubble chart, a timeline chart, and a histogram, and I want each respective link in the navigation bar to go to a page containing the appropriate chart. I know about the Navbar function in shiny, but it does not look quite the way I want. Here is mine:

```
tags$ul(class="main-nav",
        list(
             tags$li(class="active", tags$a(href="link-to-timeline-chart","Timeline Chart")),
             tags$li(tags$a(href="link-to-bubble-chart","Bubble Chart")),
             tags$li(tags$a(href="link-to-histogram","Histogram"))
  ))
```

I have even considered the option to plot them all in a single page and use the anchor tag to link to the specific part of the page containing the appropriate chart, but that would be compromising too much on my design. I really just want to have separate links for them; each in it's own page.